# Restoring nvidia-settings after resuming from suspend

Tags: suspend

This has driven me to distraction.

I've made a systemd .service file to try to restore the nvidia-settings after resuming from suspend. The driver itself is loading fine, it's the brightness settings that I need from the settings file. I'm on the Ubuntu Cosmic Cuttlefish. The service file needs to run after Xorg has started following suspend. I'm not running it from the user dir but from /etc/systemd/system dir. Should this make any difference? Anyway the service file reads:

```
[Unit]
Description=nvidia-settings
Before=sleep.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
Type=
RemainAfterExit=yes
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/home/nvidia-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

I've tried various permutations but no result so far. What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Cliff

Comment: You shouldn't need to tinker with `systemd` to make nvidia work after suspend.

Comment: Are you saying after suspend you can't change brightness?

Comment: No not that.  But every time I resume from suspend I need to run the nvidia-settings file manually via the NVIDIA X server settings, to restore the brightness setting that previously I had set.  I need to have it load automatically.

Comment: Control your Exec line should it not lead to /home/username/nvidia-settings

Comment: Correct.  Nvidia recommend though using 'nvidia-settings --load-config-only' to load that file from /home/username.   I have that file loading when the system boots up and it works.  I need to have it load when coming back from suspend.

Comment: 'nvidia-settings --load-config-only' is being loaded from a script from /home/nvidia-settings.  Just to clarify.